# Google Pay Integration - Cryptogram encoding

Tags: google-pay

I need to convert GooglePay cryptogram field to bytes. I am trying to find which encoding is used for this (highlighted in below image) field.

Can anyone please guide me?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's base64 encoded. Curious about what you need this for. It should be opaque to you as a developer.

Comment: I want to convert into byte stream. My use case is that if the cryptogram is larger than 20 bytes, I need to send (to the downstream system) it in two different fields.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? Can I ask which payment service provider or gateway you are using?